# Python code to flatten nested json to get multiple records

Tags: json, python-3.x

This is a json that i have, i need to flatten this json using python. I need records for each productId and tagName combination. Like here for productId 6 i have 2 tagName so i want 2 records in my output with all corresponding values for that tag.

I tried the below code :

def add_columns(self, obj):

```
    if "tagInfoList" in obj:
        if "tagName" in obj["dl"]:
            obj['tagName'] = obj["tagInfoList"]["tagName"]
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> output_list = [] if 'tagInfoList' in input_json:
>     for tag_info_obj in input_json['tagInfoList']:
>         temp = {'productId':input_json['productId'],'lastUpdateTime':input_json['lastUpdateTime'],'tagName':None,'tagScore':None,'postiveSnippetCount':None,'neutralSnippetCount':None,'negativeSnippetCount':None,'positiveSnippets':None,'neutralSnippets':None,'negativeSnippets':None,'negativeWithin50Char':None,'neutralWithin50Char':None,'positiveWithin50Char':None}
>         if 'tagName' in tag_info_obj:
>             temp['tagName'] = tag_info_obj['tagName']
>             temp['tagScore'] = tag_info_obj['tagScore']
>             temp['negativeSnippetCount'] = tag_info_obj['negativeSnippetCount']
>             temp['postiveSnippetCount'] = tag_info_obj['postiveSnippetCount']
>             temp['neutralSnippetCount'] = tag_info_obj['neutralSnippetCount']
>             temp['positiveSnippets'] = tag_info_obj['snippets']['positive']
>             temp['negativeSnippets'] = tag_info_obj['snippets']['negative']
>             temp['neutralSnippets'] = tag_info_obj['snippets']['neutral']
>             temp['negativeWithin50Char'] = tag_info_obj['snippetsWithin50Char']['negative']
>             temp['neutralWithin50Char'] = tag_info_obj['snippetsWithin50Char']['neutral']
>             temp['positiveWithin50Char'] = tag_info_obj['snippetsWithin50Char']['positive']
>             
>         output_list.append(temp)
> 
> print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
output_list = []
if 'tagInfoList' in input_json:
    for tag_info_obj in input_json['tagInfoList']:
        temp = {}
        if 'tagName' in tag_info_obj:
            temp[input_json['productId']] = [tag_info_obj['tagName']]
        output_list.append(temp)
print(output_list)
```

Comment: this fails with error :
for tag_info_obj in obj['tagInfoList']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: the same thing is running on my system.

Comment: what is your input ?

Comment: input is the json mentioned

Comment: is it going to be a single object ?

Comment: yes, i think. I am passing the json to the python via map reduce job like
json_obj = json.loads(line)

Comment: This does half the job.
Current output : [{'6': ['Natural Parks']}, {'6': ['New New']}]
Required output :  {'productid': '6', 'tagname': ['Natural Parks']} {'productid': '6', 'tagname': ['New New']}
also i need all columns from the json.

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the data, using [glom](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py). The example below is based on glom:

```
   #u declare a specification
   #first part is simple, return result for productId key
   #the other part looks for tagInfoList
   #and searches for tagName
   #since tagName is embedded in a list, it is wrapped with the brackets
   #u could read up more on it from the glom docs
   specs = {'productid':'productId','tags':('tagInfoList',['tagName'])}
   glom(data,specs)

  {'productid': '6', 'tags': ['Natural Parks', 'New New']}
```

Comment: i want me output like :
{'productid': '6', 'tags': ['Natural Parks']}
{'productid': '6', 'tags': ['New New']}